# how to change HTML attribute that contain hyphen

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to change value of table header's `aria-label` attribute using `execute_script`

`HTML` of target element:

```
<th class="sorting" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Activate to sort column ascending">Company</th>
```

So I try following:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("th")[1].aria-label="Activate to sort column descending";')
```

but get exception:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

If to use

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("th")[1].["aria-label"]="Activate to sort column descending";')
```

got

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

So what is the correct statement to set `aria-label` new value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `aria-label` is an attribute, you should use `.setAttribute(...)` :

```py
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('th')[1].setAttribute('aria-label', 'Activate to sort column descending');")
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the dot.

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName("th")[1]["aria-label"]="Activate to sort column descending";')
```

In JavaScript, `a.foo` is equivalent to `a["foo"]`, but the former syntax is only allowed if `foo` is a valid identifier (i.e. does not contain hyphens).